# Business card parser. How to extract related information from business card recognized texts?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have developed iphone app with OCR scanning feature.
Using Tesseract api, got the text from the image taken.
But now i need to separate each text with respect to name, address, email, phone number etc. 
Because business card structure/format is not specific, its bit of difficult to assume.

However few things assume
1) "@" containing string mostly going to be email id.
2) all digits with braces or + sign mostly going to be phone number..
but still there are lots and lots of possibilities.

Comment: Using g8Tesseract, got the text from the image. But how can I separate each text name, address and designation. What process they followed for camcard , bizcamcard or anyother app which are available in appstore? I have tried alot for R&D but no use.

Answer (score 4):

You will need the help of [NSLInguisticTagger](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class .. This is your best bet or else you will have to create similar logic for each part as you stated above.

Comment: +1 for this class, also today I learned something new :) Bad for the questioner it is available only from 5.0

Comment: ok, looks like i have to write own logic for extracting information from business card recognized text, But Are there any specifications regarding Business card format (RFC kind of thing...)???

Comment: I don't know of any particular business card formats but one think which I can advise you is to try and include QRCode scanner in your app becoz these days most of the cards contain QRCodes on them..

Comment: @Matrix out of curiosity.. for which company do you work in India...?

Comment: @Matrix I am also doing same task. How can I find  name, address and designation. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the logic we used in this Javascript BCR library, also based on tesseract (the porting in js).

https://github.com/syneo-tools-gmbh/Javascript-BCR-Library